# Shall I put 9-Patch Image in different drawable for different screen size or i can place it only one time in drawable for different screen size?

Tags: android, performance, android-drawable, nine-patch

I have one 9 patch image but i don't know that where i have to put it. only one time in Drawable folder or i have make different folder ( like mdpi,hdpi etc) in drawable for supporting different screen resolution.can anybody suggest me.thanks

Answer (score 1):

Nine Patch images are mainly used to reduce the number of images. So if you are using nine patch, there is no need to use it in different folder we can use it **drawable** folder alone. This will reduce the number of resources used in the project, which will obviously reduce the apk size too, etc...

Hope this is helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

Both `drawable/` and `drawable-*dpi/` work.

But I put all drawable *.xml files in `drawable/`, and all png/webp/jpg files in `drawable-*dpi/`, which makes the folder cleaner.

As u may use different *.9.png for different screen resolution respectively, `drawable-*dpi/` may be a better choice.

Hope it helps.